# Opening browser on a variable page using vbscript

Tags: browser, vbscript

I'm trying to write a bit of VBScript to open a browser on a specific webpage. Ultimately this webpage would be unique per script. At the moment I have the following code which works:

```
Dim objShell

objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "www.google.ie", "", "", 1)
```

But I would like to get the following working:

```
Dim iURL As String
Dim objShell

iURL = "www.google.ie"

objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1)
```

Any ideas what it is I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found out the problem was being caused in the external program launching the VBScript. Thanks for your help Alex K.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No `As String` as VBScript is not strongly type, you need a `set` when you create an instance of the COM object & no parens around the method call;

```
Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "www.google.ie"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
```

Or if chrome is the default

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run(iURL)
```

Comment: I'm using visual studio express 2012 for web and it keeps removing set and adding back in the parenthesis. I tried everything else the same way you recommend, but am getting the same result. The variable is not being used, but a direct string will work.

Comment: As a improvement you could use: `oShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", """" & iURL & """", "", "", 1` (will allow to pass parameters splitted by space without encoding it)

Comment: Thank you for sharing... OneDrive deprecated Windows 7 share.... and I need to write a simple vbs script for it... M$ is bad.. and Windows 7 ESU still deprecated in 2026... why would they drop the support *smh...

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way is to do this:

```
set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "chrome.exe"
WScript.sleep 400
WshShell.sendkeys "URL HERE"
WshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

also just a fyi you can do this to close chrome:

```
WshShell.sendkeys "%{F4}"
```

Comment: hopefully i didn't make any typos

Answer (score 1):

Can you pl insert "Call" prefix to "objShell.ShellExecute"

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

iURL = "www.google.com"

Call objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1)
```

For IE:

```
'Call objShell.ShellExecute("iexplore.exe", iURL, "", "", 1)


For more info below code also works,

Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

chrome:

```
iURL = "www.google.com"
'objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
```

ie:

```
'objShell.ShellExecute "iexplore.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Sub RickRoller()
   Dim counter, myNum, objShell, iURL
   counter = 0
   myNum = 100
   Do Until myNum = 1
     myNum = myNum - 1
     counter = counter + 1
     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAF))
   Loop
   set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   iURL = "https://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1&t=44"
   objShell.run(iURL)
 End Sub


 RickRoller()
```