# VBScript CreateObject Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scripting, vbscript, google-chrome-devtools

I have this VBScript it works fine, no problem with script but I would like to open it in Chrome instead of IE.

I am very very new to VB Scripting.
Can someone please help me.

```
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://gmail.com"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("login_username").value = "myuser"
    .getElementByID("login_password").value = "mypass"
    .getElementByID("frmLogin").submit
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: You might be able to use [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/), ie `CreateObject("ChromeTab.ChromeFrame")` but it's a long shot

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional: This looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Helen only if it works, I have not tried it

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional that didn't work either. I will need to work on writing this code in JSCRIPT.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14328348/69820

Comment: Sorry, this question was to createObject Chrome, and other one is coding helping in IE, which was helped by you :). In this I am trying to open Chrome instead of IE.

Comment: [It's in the answers of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401749/opening-browser-on-a-variable-page-using-vbscript)
Found this thread, thought it might help.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the code. There is the code for starting chrome

```
  set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   strAnswer = InputBox("Please enter a name for your new file:")
   WshShell.run "chrome.exe"
   WScript.sleep 100
   WshShell.sendkeys "www.google.com" 
   WshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because Chrome does not support VBScript. See http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions/xHWNXByKdhM

Comment: I think OP wants to do something like `WScript.CreateObject("Chrome.Application", "Chrome_")` instead of `WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")` rather than use Chrome to run this VBScript

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the correction. Thought it was the other way round due to "IE closed before script finished."

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you can only open some urls, you can't control it like you would on internet explorer

```
dim objApp : set objApp=createobject("Shell.application")
objApp.Shellexecute"chrome.exe","www.google.com","","", 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).