# vbscript to check website login and email the owner if login will fail

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a script that will open a website, login and if login will fail to email me. The reason i want to create that script is because its the only way to be sure that my login service is online. I will add that script as a scheduled task every few minutes to be sure that the login portion of my website is checked and works.

While i am not really good on vbscripts i managed to create, using a lot of reasearch, the script that will open IE and login to my website.

```
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://url.com/Login.aspx"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("ctl00_MPH_txtUserName").value = "myusername"
    .getElementByID("ctl00_MPH_txtPassword").value = "mypassword"
    .getElementByID("ctl00_BPH_btnEnterClick").Click()
  End With
End Function
Sub Wait(IE)
Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

What i need now is to make this script email me if the login will fail. Each time the login will fail it will display a "Email address or password is incorrect." string if that will help.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I see you snagged your code off of here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223765/vbscript-createobject-google-chrome?rq=1 ......So what have you tried since that?

Comment: You need code to differentiate login success and login failure, which can only be extracted from the content of the resulting website after the login has been initiated. With no example of the website it would be very difficult to give an answer to this.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your replies. Yes that was one post i followed to create the above code. I have only used the above code and i could login to my website without any issues.

To answer your second question the website will be a smartermail webmail interface ( http://www.smartertools.com/ ) and i want the script to try to login to that interface and if it will be unable to, because of the smartermail services being offline, to send an email to me so i can restart the services.

Comment: You need to define criteria whose presence (or absence) will indicate a failed login (after the click). We can't do that for you.