# Chrome: Possible to script like InternetExplorer.Application in VBScript?

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

I have a VBScript that uses InternetExplorer.Application to login to a website, then refresh the page every once in a while to keep the website from logging out due to inactivity. This sits on a dashboard screen mounted in our office. Is there a way to script Chrome in a similar way? It doesn't have to be VBScript, any language will do. We are looking to stop using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control Google Chrome as an object in VBscript. Here's why: [VBScript CreateObject Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223765/vbscript-createobject-google-chrome)

That being said, you CAN still manipulate a refresh on google chrome. Just copy the title of the page you want refreshing, and once the page has been activated, use a SendKeys command to cause it to refresh. e.g.(CTRL+R) - causes refresh, or in Sendkeys ("^r").

Once you've got it refreshing, just set it in a loop and set your wait period for however long you want.

```
'This is an infinite loop, only disposed of by exiting Wscript.exe or Cscript.exe
Do While(true)
Dim PageTitleToRefresh, IntervalinSeconds, x, objShell, Success

'Page Titles - NOT the page address - (google.com = NO) (Google = YES)
'Page Titles are normally stored at the top of the browser or in the tab name of the browser. 
PageTitleToRefresh = "Google"
IntervalinSeconds = 10

x = IntervalinSeconds * 1000
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Do Until Success = True
        Success = objShell.AppActivate(PageTitleToRefresh)
        Wscript.Sleep 1000
    Loop
    wscript.echo "Activated, now refreshing"
objShell.SendKeys "^r"

Wscript.Sleep IntervalinSeconds
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a way that I edited in js file, but can be also realized in vbs :

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");


var chrome = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
var url = 'http://google.com';

if (fso.FileExists(chrome)){
    var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application");
    objShell.ShellExecute(chrome, "--app="+url, "", "", 1);
}
else{ //if chrome doesn''t exists, so launch ie :
    oIE1 = WScript.CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application");

    oIE1.Visible = 1;
    oIE1.AddressBar = 0;
    oIE1.StatusBar = 0;
    oIE1.ToolBar = 0;
    oIE1.MenuBar = 0;
    oIE1.Navigate(url);
}
```