# VBSCRIPT "Object does not support this property or method 'document;"

Tags: vbscript

I couldn't find any answer on this topic that specifically relates to me, or any good answers that actually work.

I keep getting an error saying "Object does not support this property or method 'document'" on my code below:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

iURL = "www.wizard101.com"

Call objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1)


objShell.document.all.item("loginUserName").value = "username"
objShell.document.all.item("loginPassword").value = "password"
wscript.sleep(2000)
objShell.document.all.item("submit").click

wscript.sleep(2000)
```

To be honest, I'm pretty sure I know what the issue is, I'm trying to edit objShell when objShell is defined as a Web Browser directory. But what I'm asking is how to fix this. How would I still be able to edit web elements while also finding Google Chrome and bringing the user to a specific website? Thanks.

Comment: "I couldn't find any answer on this topic that specifically relates to me" - That’s the problem, what you’ll find here is a why that error occurs then you need to work through it based on which line errors and work it back. Basically the `objShell` which is an instance of the `Shell.Application` does not contain a `document` property or method, which is correct. You're assuming you can access the web page DOM via a shell execute call which is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: Possible to script like InternetExplorer.Application in VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683839/chrome-possible-to-script-like-internetexplorer-application-in-vbscript)