# Open specific webpage and autofill fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a website that needs to be logged into on multiple computers IOT allow examinees to take a test.
I have written a .vbs that works perfect if the user has IE.  However I can't figure out how to write a JavaScript or any other code language to work with Chrome.  The site works equally well with either browser, sometimes the test is taken on a Chromebook without IE installed.

Here is my .vbs:

```
REM Save as .vbs, select save as all in drop down, 
REM type .vbs in place of .txt

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://www.dmdc.osd.mil/icat/loginCEP.do"
IE.FullScreen = True
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 50
Wend

Set ipf = IE.document.all.username
ipf.Value = "username" REM replace with your username 
Set ipf = IE.document.all.password
ipf.Value = "password" REM replace with your password 

Set ipf = IE.document.all.sess_id
ipf.Value = "nnnnnn"

Set ipf = IE.document.all.st_id  
ipf.Value = "nn" REM first 2 numbers of school code
Set ipf = IE.document.all.cnt_id
ipf.Value = "nnn" REM next 3 numbers of school code
Set ipf = IE.document.all.sch_id
ipf.Value = "nnnn" REM last 4 numbers of school code
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223765/vbscript-createobject-google-chrome

Comment: Does not answer my question. thanks though.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: The goal here is to write a program that can go in (for example) whatever a Chromebook has instead of a Start Menu which will launch a browser and then fill in a login form automatically. Is that correct?

Comment: Please post a few input data as example, as well as the HTML content of the page you want to fill.

Comment: @besciualex — All that can be inferred from the code in the question … but that isn't the tricky part of the question which is about how to automate the browser on Chrome OS.

Comment: Have you considered a Chrome extension which is purely JS?

Comment: Also please consider adding comments to your code. Who is ipf? I for example know JS, but not a single piece of VBS... and not the whole algorithm posted is self explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like VBScript is not supported for Chrome yet. If you want to learn the basics of JavaScript, you can look for free classes. JavaScript is supported for all modern browsers. To build a website you basically need to learn three things: HTML, JavaScript and CSS. There are many other frameworks you can learn, like Angular CLI; but that is more advanced. What is great about learning Angular CLI in the future, is that you can scale your applications with ease. You can choose to use something like TypeScript or SCSS that compiles and polyfills the JavaScript and CSS for you, so all/older browser gets supported also almost guaranteed. But you can just test it yourself for now in e.g. Edge and Chrome. Angular CLI is not needed for that thought. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) have some good tutorials.

Underneath is a simple website... You can include the JavaScript and CSS directly into the HTML if want (like done here) I also recommend using the application [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for coding... But if you want live testing for smaller websites live without installing anything, you can use something like [Brackets](http://brackets.io/):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your document</title>
</head>
<style>
    /* CSS */
    body {
        font-size: 90px;
    }
    #button0 {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1 id="h1_0">Hello</h1>
    <button id="button0" onclick="changeHeader()">
        Change the header
    </button>
    
    <!-- JavaScript (you want to run the JS after the HTML-element has been loaded usally...) -->
    <script>
        function changeHeader() {
            var header = document.getElementById('h1_0');

            header.innerHTML += ' Hello You';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you should always think about security... So don't keep the answers hidden on a website. Use a server for that... But if you are going to create a test, you probably know the answers, or keep them somewhere safe to check manually afterwards, so you don't need think about that for now! I also recommend creating like a template you can (for now) just copy and paste, and fill in, if you are going to create several tests.

You should also probably prevent updating the website, so the student don't do that accidentally. And think about how you want to display and store the finished data, if you are going to receive it. A server and database could do the trick, but it is more advanced, so maybe download it locally.

Maybe your examinies tests are not serious? Just a test for themself? That would make it a whole lot easier, because they would only be the ones loosing if they cheated on that.

I can help get you started if you want as a small job, but it is fun trying it out yourself.

**Note:**
If you don't want to update the page itself with JavaScript code to handle automation and use external software as suggested by another user, you can use something like [Wildfire Browser Automation](https://wildfire.ai/) for Chrome. There are other alternatives also. JavaScript is a client-side language, and will not work the same way VBScript will, if you run it in Windows CMD, because it is not what it is made for. You could make students use something like [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) to fill in the fields (use dev. tools to locate the fields ID) by giving them a script.

Comment: The question is about automating a browser from an external program, not writing client-side code that is part of a website.

Comment: You might want to read the VBScript code in the question. It runs using Windows Scripting Host to launch Internet Explorer, navigate to a URL, and then fill it in. (It **doesn't** run in a `<script language="vbscript">` in a webpage). They want to achieve the same effect on a computer running Chrome OS instead of Windows.

Comment: @Quentin Well, you can not use JavaScript in a website for automation from a website (without using the dev. tools) which you have no control over and/or maybe blocks embedding (same origin policy). You can not use JavaScript as an external automation script file like VBScript, because that is not what it is made for. The best option would be to add more JS-code on the website so it can handle the automation with data from the URL (if possible). Or use something like [Wildfire Browser Automation](https://wildfire.ai/) for Chrome.

Comment: "You can not use JavaScript as an external automation script file like VBScript" — I can (and do). (I don't know if it is possible on Chrome OS otherwise I'd have answered).

Comment: "best option would be to add more JS-code on the website so it can handle the automation with data from the URL (if possible). " — That would require the OP to have control over the website (which doesn't seem likely).

Comment: @Quentin "You can not use JavaScript as an external automation script file like VBScript" — I can (and do). (I don't know if it is possible on Chrome OS otherwise I'd have answered). — Well then go ahead and post an answer then; what are you waiting for. :-) In terms of running it like he does now, no I don't think you do. As a dev. I could also do that, as a student, I don't think it would be very easy the first time.

Comment: I literally just said I don't know if it is possible *on Chrome OS* which the question is about. I specifically said that was why I hadn't written an answer! Also, at no point as the OP said they were a student.

Comment: "runs in every modern browser" — It runs in a bunch of other places as well (like Windows Scripting Host and Mac Scripting which is what you'd use for a task like this.

Comment: "He mentioned examinees, which are often students" — The OP said it was for them to use, not that they were one of them.

Comment: "he never mentioned having to use an external program to complete his task" — They provided code, written in VBScript, which **is** an external program. So while they didn't say so explicitly, they did so by example.

Comment: "that it will not work like VBScript running in something like Windows CMD" — It will. Again, see Windows Scripting Host.

Comment: Sorry for confusion in my question IOT means in order to. Also I am the test administrator not a student