# i try this code but does not work

Tags: vbscript

```
msgbox("{welcome to in IRCTC}")

On Error Resume Next

Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Execute"C:\Users\ASFRAF\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.exe"

Call objShell.Navigate("https://www.irctc.co.in/cgi-bin/bv60.dll/irctc/services/login.do?userName=namanja&password=vishal123&submit=Login")

msgbox("go to login in irctc")

objShell.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

msgbox("success login in irctc")
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good description of any problem. Do you get any error messages? Does it not compile? Does a nearby coffee maker start singing unexpectedly?

Comment: Chrome does not have VBScript support, so you cannot use it as a `COM` object as you could do with Internet Explorer. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401749/opening-browser-on-a-variable-page-using-vbscript) question how you can open a page on Chrome from VBScript (but you can't interact with it).

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, The global `On Error Resume Next` is masking any error you're getting. **Never** use `On Error Resume Next` unless you know *exactly* what you're doing *and* have sensible error handling code in place.

With that said, judging from the `objIE` variable in the `Do` loop it looks like you tried to modify a script for Internet Explorer automation so it'd use Chrome instead of IE. That doesn't work, because Chrome doesn't expose a COM object that could be controlled via VBScript.

Other mistakes in your code, which are hidden by the global `On Error Resume Next`:

1. You're trying to assign an object instance to a variable without using the `Set` keyword (`objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")`).
2. [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects don't have an `Execute` method. If you want to run external programs via the `Shell` object you need to use the [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. However, that method launches the process asynchronously in the background and doesn't return a handle to it.
3. `Shell` objects also don't have a `Navigate` method. That method is provided by the [`InternetExplorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object.

Something like this should work:

```
MsgBox "{welcome to in IRCTC}"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "https://www.irctc.co.in/cgi-bin/..."

MsgBox "go to login in irctc"

ie.Visible = True
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop

MsgBox "success login in irctc"
```

But I guess that's what you already had.