# Attempting to pass flag to use Chrome via RemoteApp

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm new to VBS but attempting to figure this out on my own but I'm getting to the end of my rope. I have a VBS script that I am using from another poster to open Chrome via RemoteApp on 2008 R2. The script I'm using is:

```
Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "www.google.com"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
```

[Opening browser on a variable page using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401749/opening-browser-on-a-variable-page-using-vbscript)

After getting this to initially launch Chrome via RemoteApp, I found that Chrome crashes without loading the page (doesn't matter what the URL is). Further research led me to [this page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79091#c51), which recommended including the flag `--allow-no-sandbox-job` when launching Chrome via RemoteApp.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to include the above flag within the initial VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL & " --allow-no-sandbox-job"  , "", "", 1
```