# Is there a function or command that I can use to call up default browser in my code

Tags: vbscript

I have a code that specifies a specific type of browser to be used when opening a link, now I want the code to open the link using the computer's default browser instead of the specified browser.

I have set the line of code to "defaultbrowser.application" and "default_browser.application" instead of "InternetExplorer.application"

```
 Sub sbExitHTA
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = true
 IE.Navigate2 "yahoo.com"
'IE.Navigate2 "yahoo.com"

'<a href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> 
  Self.Close()
```

I want the code to open my computer's default browser which is not internet explorer instead of internet explorer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening browser on a variable page using vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401749/opening-browser-on-a-variable-page-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses your default browser:

```
Dim objWScriptShell
Set objWScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objWScriptShell.Run "https://yahoo.com", 9
```

[Here is documentation](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp) about the Run command and the `intWindowStyle` parameter (I used 9 here).

Comment: Kindly explain more

Comment: Did you try the code? What do you want extra information about?

Comment: Thanks Etienne, I figured out what I have to edit and insert your code and it worked like magic, thank you so much.

Comment: Great, glad it worked! Please mark the answer as accepted using the gray check mark to the left of the answer! Please come back to Stack Overflow when you have new programming questions.

Comment: Done. Please can I send you a message?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there is no user-to-user messaging in Stack Overflow...
[How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: Okay. I just want to know more about it. Like how I can call up a browser manually.
Like calling up Chrome or Edge instead of the default browser this time.